# How to scale "probabilities" to a given mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods

I have a set of scores $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,N$ (mimicking probabilities, $0\le x_i\le 1$) and I want to transform them so that the result has a given mean $m$, while remaining in the interval $[0;1]$.

IOW, I am looking for a *reasonable* (in particular, smooth and strictly increasing) function $f(x): [0;1]\mapsto [0;1]$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$.

One transformation which makes sense to me is this:

1. convert probabilities to odds: $o_i=\frac{1-x_i}{x_i}$ (new range is $[0;\infty]$)
2. multiply the odds by a positive factor $\lambda$
3. convert the scaled odds back to probabilities: $y_i=\frac{1}{1+\lambda o_i}$

**The question is**: how do I find $\lambda$?

Here is a recursive `R` function, which scales the odds by the ratio of the desired mean over the actual mean:

```
set.mean <- function (p, m, eps=sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) { # make mean of p equal to m
  m1 <- mean(p)
  if (abs(m-m1) < eps)
    return(p)
  set.mean(1/(1 + (m1/m) * (1/p - 1)), m, eps)
}
```

It converges too slowly. I guess I can use the Newton's method for faster conversion, but I wonder if there is some brilliant trick which would solve my problem.

PS. *reasonable* in this case means just that: I should be able to *reason* that it makes sense to transform probabilities this way :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you want the set of scores $\{x_1, \dots, x_N\}$ to have a given mean $m$?  They already have a mean and it's going to be in $[0, 1]$.  Do you want the function $f$, which depends on the data, to satisfy $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$ such that $\{ f(x_i) \}$ now has mean $m$?

Comment: @ShawnO'Hare: yes, this is what I mean; is it better now?

Comment: Another class of functions you might think about for the transformation is $x^r$ where $r$ is a positive real.  I don't know if this would be easier to work with than your odds function.

Comment: @paw88789: yeah, I thought about it; I think it is harder to justify and more expensive computationally. I am still open to that option too though

Comment: @sds: With the power transformation from my previous comment, you could try iteratively choosing $r$ so that the current mean, $m_1$ goes to the desired mean $m$.  So $r$ would satisfy $m_1^r=m$, or $r=\frac{\ln(m)}{\ln(m_1)}$.  I don't know how fast it would converge, but it worked well on the one example I tried.

Comment: So you just want to choose $\lambda$ so as to make the mean equal to a specified number $m$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: yes, precisely!

Comment: The odds method works well in Excel with Solver: minimize (target mean- actual mean)$^2$ - takes 2 sec.